# Hangman while loop not working with ||

Tags: java, while-loop

I have the following while-loop for a game of Hangman I'm working on:

```
while(amountOfGuessesLeft > 0 || !wordComplete){
        System.out.println("The word now looks like this: " + filteredWord);
        System.out.println("You have " + amountOfGuessesLeft + " guesses left");
        System.out.print("Your guess: ");
        try {
            guess = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(guess.length() == 0 || guess.length() > 1){
            System.out.println("Please just type one letter. Try again.");
        }else if(wordSelected.contains(guess) || wordSelected.contains(guess.toUpperCase())){
            System.out.println("That guess is correct.");
            filteredWord = showGuess(filteredWord, wordLetters,  guess.toUpperCase().charAt(0));
            if(!filteredWord.contains("_")){
                wordComplete = true;
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("There are no " + guess.toUpperCase() + "'s in this word.");
            amountOfGuessesLeft--;
        }
    }
```

When the while-loop condition is just amountOfGuessesLeft > 0, everything works fine. However, when I add || !wordComplete, neither condition is applied and the loop never ends. It doesn't throw any errors either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @GBlodgett when I run the program and `amountOfGuessesLeft` reaches 0 the program just keeps asking me for another guess. `wordComplete` is initialized before the loop with false. I'll add the part before the loop with an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `&&`.

You want to run the loop as long as there are any guesses left **and** the user hasn't found the word yet.

Currently, if you run out of guesses and still haven't found the word, `!wordComplete` will evaluate to `true` and allows the loop to be executed again.

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate it. Sorry for not trying that. I guess I was adamant that it was `||` that I didn't try `&&`.

Comment: @RoyHenriquez Glad I could help. Remember to accept an answer if your problem is solved!